# Data frame with Hidden column values

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

1. The data frame consists of column 'value' which has some hidden characters.
2. When I write the data frame to PostgreSQL I get the below error 
   `ValueError: A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters.`
3. I some how found the cause of error. Refer table below (missing column value

```
|       | datetime                 | mc | tagname | value      | quality |
|-------|--------------------------|----|---------|------------|---------|
| 19229 | 16-12-2021 02:31:29.083  | L  | VIN     |            | 192     |
| 19230 | 16-12-2021 02:35:28.257  | L  | VIN     | C4A 173026 | 192     |
```

4. Checked the length of string- it was same 10 character like below rows 
   [image]

```
df.value.str.len()
```

[image]

Requirement: 
I want to replace that empty area with text 'miss', i tried different method in pandas. I'm not able to do.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace(r"[\"\',]", '')<br />
df.replace('\'','', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

```
|       | datetime                 | mc | tagname | value      | quality |
|-------|--------------------------|----|---------|------------|---------|
| 19229 | 16-12-2021 02:31:29.083  | L  | VIN     | miss       | 192     |
| 19230 | 16-12-2021 02:35:28.257  | L  | VIN     | C4A 173026 | 192     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace(r'[\x00-\x19]', '').replace('', 'miss')
```